# Realm: query with property aggregation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, realm

I have 2 objects: Person and Transaction. Person can have multiple transactions (1-many). Now I want to get all persons, who have sum(transactions.amount) > 0. How can I do it most efficient way?

My models setup:

```
class Person: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var transactions = RLMArray(objectClassName: Transaction.className())

    var balance: Int {
        var balance = 0
        for transaction in self.transactions {
            let transaction = transaction as Transaction;
            balance += transaction.amount
        }

        return balance
    }
}

class Transaction: RLMObject {
    dynamic var amount = 0
}
```

And attempt to query:

```
let debtPersons = Person.objectsWhere("balance < 0")
let creditPersons = Person.objectsWhere("balance >= 0")
```

On this naive approach receiving:

```
'Invalid column name', reason: 'Column name balance not found in table'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm currently does not support doing aggregate queries, so there's no one-liner to perform the query you want. Additionally, Realm is unable to query un-persisted properties (as `balance` is, in this case), because they are not in the database. Your best bet is to manually filter all of the `Person` objects, instead of using a native query.